# JavaScript library to create charts and graphs

Tags: library, javascript, charts

When I’m creating dynamic charts, I want to fetch new data from data source periodically and refresh the chart. Can you recommend a good charting library (JavaScript)?

There are other requirements:

1. Compatibility in all platforms.

   For some resons, I have to use IE8, so I want a chart  supporting it.
2. Supply iOS and Android native charts library for users.
3. Strong data analysis.

   Including legend switch, data hotspot tip, chart linkage, auto refresh at regular time, series drag, drill down and scale.
4. Data display in multiple forms.

   It’s perfect to support text, value, time, date, percentage, scientific notation, etc.

Comment: Not giving an answer since I cannot take the time I need to check your requirements and I do not understand your #2. [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) comes with great features but you [probably have to pay for it](http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html). On the other hand, I also used [Flotcharts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) in the past, though you require jQuery to use this one.

Comment: Thank you,Chop. I'm not care about whether the javascrip libary is free or payable.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [jsgraphs.com](http://www.jsgraphs.com/) (JS graphing library comparison).

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked out ZingChart? It meets a majority of your requirements.

1. The current build is compatible with IE6+, along with other modern browsers. It can render using canvas and svg. (VML and Flash for legacy browsers).
2. While there is no direct support for native charts, ZingChart does work on mobile browsers. If it is an option, both Android and iOS support webview to embed pages in your app.
3. All of that and more! http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/
4. Data formatting : http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/data-formatting/

The library is free to use with a branded watermark, or can be unbranded and packaged with a number of support and developer hours.

I'm on the ZingChart team so feel free to reach out if you have any questions or other needs. We are also open to working with customers to develop features to suit their needs.

Comment: Thank you very much！I‘ll try ZingChart. If I have other questions, I'll ask you again.

Comment: How many types of data sources do ZingChart support? Including JSON?

Comment: ZingChart supports JSON, CSV, array values, (http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/data-sources/) and the ability to format the data in a number of ways (http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/data-formatting/ )

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at [VanCharts](http://www.vancharts.com/).

Vancharts provides charts refresh function. You can set a fixed time interval ,automatically fetch and dynamic refresh the chart.

Code example:

```
"interaction": {

    "autoRefresh": 2,

    "zoom": true,

    "draggable": true
 }
```

1. JavaScript chart library VanCharts is based on Canvas but is compatible with all existing browsers, including Safari, Chrome, IE6+ and Firefox.
2. VanCharts supports two ways of integration in mobile terminals: web and native.
3. Of course! VanCharts can do that.
4. It can display data in multiple forms and supports over 30 chart types, including bar chart, line chart, pie chart, doughnut chart, map, GIS map, Gantt chart.

http://www.vancharts.com/demo.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I want to know if VanCharts supports JSON.

Comment: Yes, VanCharts supports JSON. And  users only needs to provide a JSON URL.

Answer (score 2):

here go three pieces of software that may serve you:

- [Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) - Interactive charts for browsers and mobile devices (by Google).
- [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) - A JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data.
- [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) - Simple, clean and engaging charts for designers and developers.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Chart for JS](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line) can satisfy your requirements.

1. It is compatible with IE8 and other commonly used browsers.
2. iOS and Android native charts are also available - it is a separate package, but the API is common to the extent possible. [Essential Chart for iOS](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/ios/Chart) [Essential Chart for Android](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/android/Chart). Essential Chart for JS can also be used in mobile applications (hybrid).
3. All of the data analysis features you have mentioned are supported.
4. Data can be displayed with different formats.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program.

Disclaimer: I’m working for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

SciChart's [JavaScript Chart](https://www.scichart.com/javascript-chart-features/) supports the following criteria from your OP

[image: Interactive JavaScript Chart]

- Provides compatibility with all major browsers including Chrome, Edge, Safari, iOS Safari, Android browser, Opera
- Has a native [iOS Charts](https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-features/) and native [Android chart library](https://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features/) as well for Swift/Java/Kotlin apps on mobile (not a Swift/Kotlin wrapper around a javascript chart like other libraries
- Includes features you requested such as Legend, Crosshair/cursor, Chart linking, refresh on data or property update, scale
- Drilldown can be constructed via hit-test APIs (detect click on points)
- Series drag can be constructed via ChartModifiers APIs
- Supports ~30 chart types in 2D and 3D
- Supports text, value, time, dates, percentage (ratio) and scientific/engineering notation on axis as well

Answer (score 0):

[Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) JavaScript plotting for jQuery

[Morris](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)

[Sparkline](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) small inline charts

Answer (score 0):

There is now a **super-fast library** for real-time data monitoring, and interactivity during data acquisition, [LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/).

[image: Fast streaming charts]

It's made with **WebGL**, using GPU primitives to render the charts and graphs. The real-time performance is in totally different level than with other JavaScript charts.

It works in web, mobile and desktop, a true cross-platform chart.

As tech lead of LightningChart, I've been involved in the development of the library for several years.